# Github authenticate with an access token authorized to a GitHub App in order to list installations

Tags: reactjs, github, oauth, repository

I am trying to fetch list of installations from github.

I have generated an access-token as mentioned in given documentation.
https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps#2-users-are-redirected-back-to-your-site-by-github

Now I am using same access-token to call installations api as below API. (passing Authentication value as "Bearer ".

```
https://api.github.com/user/installations
```

Such information is given in the following link.
https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps#check-which-installations-resources-a-user-can-access

When I try to hit installations api, it given following error:

```
You must authenticate with an access token authorized to a GitHub App in order to list installations
```

Basically I am trying to achieve following steps given the the docs:
https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps#web-application-flow
and
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/apps#list-app-installations-accessible-to-the-user-access-token

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Github App you created is actually a Github App **and not an OAuth app**. You can check this by making sure it is listed on this page: [https://github.com/organizations/{your-organization-id}/settings/apps](https://github.com/organizations/%7Byour-organization-id%7D/settings/apps).

The access token used to trigger the operation must have been requested using this Github App (the client id is in the **About** section of the page [https://github.com/organizations/{your-organization-id}/settings/apps/{app-id}](https://github.com/organizations/%7Byour-organization-id%7D/settings/apps/%7Bapp-id%7D)).